# Explicit resolving of ILog in Autofac when using with Log Injection Module

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, log4net, autofac

I use the following code in order to register log4net for all the classes that need it.

```
public class LogInjectionModule : Module
{
    private readonly string _configPath;

    public LogInjectionModule(string configPath)
    {
        _configPath = configPath;
    }

    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry registry,
        IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(_configPath));

        registration.Preparing += OnComponentPreparing;
    }

    private static void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = e.Component.Activator.LimitType;
        e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(new[]
                                          {
                                              new ResolvedParameter((p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof (ILog),
                                                  (p, i) => LogManager.GetLogger(t))
                                          });
    }
}
```

All the classes are registered using autofac's types scanning:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof (IResourceFinder).Assembly)
 .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

**And it works fine!**

**One class needs to be registered explicitly tries to resolve ILog and fails**

```
builder.Register(x => new ClassThatNeedsILog(x.Resolve<ILog>())).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Here is that class

```
public class ClassThatNeedsILog
{
    public ClassThatNeedsILog(ILog log)
    {

    }
}
```

**I am getting the following exception:**

> Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException : The
>   requested service 'log4net.ILog' has not been registered. To avoid
>   this exception, either register a component to provide the service,
>   check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the
>   ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `LogInjectionModule` **never registers any `ILog`**  into the container only supplies paramters for the resolved instances on the preparing face, and it **only works for instances created by Autofac.**

So when you write `builder.Register(x => new ClassThatNeedsILog(x.Resolve<ILog>()))` you are creating the `ClassThatNeedsILog` manually. with `new ClassThatNeedsILog(...)`

Hence Autofac does not know about your instance creation (so your `OnComponentPreparing` won't run) and because you haven't really registered any `ILog` implementation you get the `ComponentNotRegisteredException`.

You have two options:

- register an `ILog` in the container directly
- let Autofac create your `ClassThatNeedsILog` type.

So you can just register an `ILog` in the container with:

```
builder.RegisterInstance(LogManager.GetLogger("Logger")).As<ILog>();
```

Then your code will work fine.

Or if you anyway creating the `ClassThatNeedsILog` by hand can just supply directly the `ILog` there:

```
 builder.Register(x => new 
     ClassThatNeedsILog(LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ClassThatNeedsILog))))
     .AsImplemen‌​tedInterfaces();
```

The other options is to let Autofac create the instances for you, so change your registration to:

```
 builder.RegisterType<ClassThatNeedsILog>()
     .AsImplemen‌​tedInterfaces();
```

In this case Autofac will handle the instance creation for you and it will call the `OnComponentPreparing` method of your module.

If you want to supply [additional constructor parameters](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Autowiring#Additional_Constructor_Arguments) you can use `WithParameter` and `WithParameters` methods:

```
 builder.RegisterType<ClassThatNeedsILog>()
     .AsImplemen‌​tedInterfaces()
     .WithParameters(new Parameter[] {
         ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IAnotherInterface>("NAME"),
         ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IYetAnotherInterface>("ANOTHERNAME")});
```

Comment: nemesv, Thank you for your detailed answer. I am familiar with the two options you suggested. Actually I use the first one as the temporary workaround till I found a better solution. I am not happy with this option, since it eliminates the whole purpose of LogInjectionModule, which injects specific instance of ILog<T> with the relleavnt T of the class it injects to. The second option you suggest is not acceptable in my case because ClassThatNeedsILog receives a few more dependent interfaces which need to be resolved by name: x.ResolveNamed<IAnotherInterface>("NAME").

Comment: Actually I do not want to manally create instance if ClassThatNeedsILog, but I am looking for syntax similar to Unity, which allows to tell "when resolving this class, use for resolving this": http://mikaelkoskinen.net/unity-passing-constructor-parameters-to-resolve/

Comment: @BorisModylevsky If you want to supply additional parameters you can do it with the `WithParameter` method in Autofac, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `builder` needs to `Build` a `container` before it can `Resolve`.

Try something like this (untested)

```
builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof (IResourceFinder).Assembly)
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
/* process LogInjectionModule */
IContainer container = builder.Build();

var updateBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
updateBuilder
    .Register(x => new ClassThatNeedsILog(x.Resolve<ILog>()))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
updateBuilder.Update(container);
```

Comment: I guess, it would work. Will test later, but I would not like to build  the container and then update. There are a lot of other registrations and it starts looking clumsy. It also works if I register the ILog directly, like this: builder.RegisterInstance(LogManager.GetLogger("Logger")).As<ILog>();

Comment: Your code in its current form is not working, it still throws the same exception... OP's problem is that there is no `ILog` registered directly in the container (the `LogInjectionModule` does not do this)  so the `Update` won't helps here. If there is `ILog` registered the `.Register(x => new ClassThatNeedsILog(x.Resolve<ILog>()))` would be enough and there is no need for the `Update`.

Answer (score 0):

nemesv's answer resolved the issue for me.

Though, I had to spend some more time getting it to work after using the RegisterType approach, as I was missing the below:

```
config.Filters.AddRange(config.DependencyResolver.GetServices(typeof(IExceptionFilter)).Select(o => o as IExceptionFilter));
```

Just adding mentioning it here, if other's have forgotten to configure the filter in the first place.