# Using log4net with Autofac

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am trying to use log4net with Autofac.
I've pasted this code http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/log4net.html ,
and from Program.cs/Main() I am doing

```
var iocBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
iocBuilder.RegisterModule(new LoggingModule());
var iocContainer = iocBuilder.Build();
```

now I would like to try this out immediately (in the next line),
writing a simple line to the log file. How should I do it?

I am thinking of something like this

```
var ls = iocContainer.Resolve<LoggingModule>();
ls.Info("the logging is working");
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To obtain a `ILog`, log4net need to know the class that use the logger (`LogManager.GetLogger(...)`). So, you can't resolve a `ILog` without a parent class. You have to inject the `ILog` inside a component.

```
public class MyComponent
{
     public MyComponent(ILog logger)
     {
          this._logger = logger; 
     }

     private readonly ILog _logger; 

     public void Do()
     { 
          this._logger.Info("Log4net OK");
     }
}
```

*In the application start (Global.asax.cs for Asp.net, MVC):*

```
// ...
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
// ...
iocBuilder.RegisterModule(new LoggingModule());
iocBuilder.RegisterType<MyComponent>().AsSelf(); 

// ...

MyComponent c = iocContainer.Resolve<MyComponent>();
c.Do();
```

Another solution would be to register an `ILog` for `Object` and resolve `ILog`. In this case, the module is not required.

//In the DI container builder:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
/// ...
ContainerBuilder cb = new ContainerBuilder()
cb.Register(c => LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Object))).As<ILog>();
IContainer container = cb.Build();
```

//In the function where we need to ue the logger:

```
ILog logger = container.Resolve<ILog>();
logger.Info("log4net OK");
```

Comment: thank you. I am a Step further thanks to ur comment. Though it says. The requested service 'log4net.ILog' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

Comment: all right, now the problem can be continued using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778170/explicit-resolving-of-ilog-in-autofac-when-using-with-log-injection-module

Comment: add  log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); inside MyComponent() constructor

Comment: You don't need to add `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();` inside `MyComponent` constructor. This call is required only once per application

Comment: This code example does not correspond autofac log4net module mentioned by OP, Just having public ILog property is enough. There is no need for constructor injection.